# Question about birthday attack on password

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking

Based on birthday attack, you need to generate at least 2^n/2 of possible combination to have 50% chance of finding a password. I have a list of 3000 random password make from 16 characters of upper, lower characters(That's 50^16 possible combinations) hashed into MD5. How many possible combinations i have to look up to find at least half the result of password list above?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the birthday paradox applies here.

The birthday paradox states that in your case, if you have 4.6 × 10<sup>13</sup> passwords, there is a 50% chance that two are the same.

However, you only have 3000 password hashes. So you would have to look up in the order of 50<sup>16</sup>/3000 passwords.

The chance that a random password is in your collection is 1-(1-1/50<sup>16</sup>)<sup>3000</sup>. If you try 10<sup>23</sup> passwords you have a chance of 
(1-(1-1/50<sup>16</sup>)<sup>3000</sup>) × 10<sup>23</sup> ≈ 20%.